# I am trying to run cabal build, and I get the following error

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

```
Build profile: -w ghc-9.0.1 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - csound-expression-dynamic-0.3.8 (lib) (requires build)
 - csound-expression-typed-0.2.7 (lib) (requires build)
 - csound-expression-opcodes-0.0.5.1 (lib) (requires build)
 - csound-expression-5.3.4 (lib) (requires build)
 - csound-sampler-0.0.10.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - csound-catalog-0.7.4 (lib) (requires build)
 - solve-0.2.0.0 (exe:solve) (first run)
Starting     csound-expression-dynamic-0.3.8 (lib)
Building     csound-expression-dynamic-0.3.8 (lib)

Failed to build csound-expression-dynamic-0.3.8.
Build log (
C:\Users\Shiro\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\ghc-9.0.1\csound-expres_-0.3.8-3e9f98bb37e846ae1dd789bc6c80c4d50504a214.log
):
Preprocessing library for csound-expression-dynamic-0.3.8..
Building library for csound-expression-dynamic-0.3.8..
[ 1 of 15] Compiling Csound.Dynamic.Tfm.DeduceTypes ( src\Csound\Dynamic\Tfm\DeduceTypes.hs, dist\build\Csound\Dynamic\Tfm\DeduceTypes.o )
[ 2 of 15] Compiling Csound.Dynamic.Tfm.UnfoldMultiOuts ( src\Csound\Dynamic\Tfm\UnfoldMultiOuts.hs, dist\build\Csound\Dynamic\Tfm\UnfoldMultiOuts.o )
[ 3 of 15] Compiling Csound.Dynamic.Types.Exp ( src\Csound\Dynamic\Types\Exp.hs, dist\build\Csound\Dynamic\Types\Exp.o )

src\Csound\Dynamic\Types\Exp.hs:202:66: error:
    * No instance for (Data.Functor.Classes.Eq1 RatedExp)
        arising from a use of `=='
    * In the second argument of `(&&)', namely
        `(ratedExpExp re == EmptyExp)'
      In the expression:
        isNothing (ratedExpDepends re) && (ratedExpExp re == EmptyExp)
      In an equation for `isEmptyExp':
          isEmptyExp e
            = isNothing (ratedExpDepends re) && (ratedExpExp re == EmptyExp)
            where
                re = unFix e
    |
202 | isEmptyExp e = isNothing (ratedExpDepends re) && (ratedExpExp re == EmptyExp)
    |                                                                  ^^
cabal.exe: Failed to build csound-expression-dynamic-0.3.8 (which is required
by exe:solve from solve-0.2.0.0). See the build log above for details.
```

This my first time touching Haskell and Cabal. So, from what I understand, I need solve.exe, which needs csound-expression-dynamic-0.3.8, which needs something else. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ratedExpExp re == EmptyExp` was earlier in the file than `$(deriveEq1 ''RatedExp)` was. [GHC 9.0.1's release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/9.0.1-notes.html) say this:

> - Breaking change: Template Haskell splices now act as separation points
>   between constraint solving passes. It is no longer possible to use
>   an instance of a class before a splice and define that instance after a splice.
>   For example, this code now reports a missing instance for `C Bool`:
>
>   ```
>   class C a where foo :: a
>   bar :: Bool
>   bar = foo
>   $(return [])
>   instance C Bool where foo = True
>   ```

That can be fixed by moving the `isEmptyExp` method to after the `$(deriveEq1 ''RatedExp)` splice. Once you do that, you'll run into another error about a duplicate instance. That can be fixed by by wrapping `instance Hashable1 IM.IntMap` inside of a `#if !MIN_VERSION_hashable(1,3,4)`, after which it will compile fine on GHC 9.0.1. I opened https://github.com/spell-music/csound-expression-dynamic/pull/3 to make these changes upstream, but until they're accepted, you can make them manually to get it to build.

**UPDATE:** My PR to fix this was merged and a new version was uploaded to Hackage. After doing a `cabal update`, building on GHC 9 should now succeed with no changes required to your project.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `csound-expression-dynamic` is not yet compatible with GHC 9.0.1. Try GHC 8.10.7, which is still the recommended version for general use.

I've opened an issue about this on their GitHub page: https://github.com/spell-music/csound-expression-dynamic/issues/2.